# Maven-java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: INSTANCE when testing with Appium

Tags: maven, appium

I have Maven project that tests some Mobile application with Appium. When I try to run it from `mvn test -Dtest=AppiumTest` I get **below exception**

[image]

**below is my pom.xml dependancy:**

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.appium</groupId>
    <artifactId>java-client</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
<groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
<artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
<version>4.3.2</version>
</dependency>
```

Because of above exception, configuration is failing which is written in @BeforeTest.
How can it be resolved? I am creating Driver instance as below:

```
driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub"),capabilities);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The class with the error is in the `httpcore` library, a dependency of `httpclient`. Maybe some other library is pulling an older version.

Try adding to your `pom.xml`:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
    <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
    <version>4.3.2</version>
</dependency>
```

Or an above version.

You can also see the maven dependency tree with the command to see which version the project is using:

```
mvn dependency:tree -Dverbose -Dincludes=httpcore
```

In `verbose` mode, the dependency tree shows dependencies that were omitted for: being a duplicate of another, conflicting with another's version and/or scope, and introducing a cycle into the dependency tree.

https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/examples/resolving-conflicts-using-the-dependency-tree.html

https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/examples/filtering-the-dependency-tree.html

Comment: :With above command I could resolve the dependency issue. Now my code is communicating with Appium. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

**NoSuchFieldError:** Thrown if an application tries to access or modify a specified field of an object, and that object no longer has that field.
Normally, this error is caught by the compiler; this error can only occur at run time if the definition of a class has incompatibly changed.

---

**Solution:**
This error is typically thrown if you only partially recompile your code. You've got old code that is referencing a field that no longer exists in the recompiled class files.The solution is to clean out all the class files and compile everything from fresh.

If the error is still thrown during runtime, then you probably compile using one version of a library, but use another version at runtime. You must verify that your classpath contains the proper version of the specified library.

Also try to use:

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>io.appium</groupId>
            <artifactId>java-client</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
 </dependency>
```

Comment: Yes with above Appium Java client version & httpclient 4.3.1 my code is finally communicating with appium. Thanks!